# Eloquent mapping table relation using five models in laravel 4

Tags: model, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I have a project which is loading the menus from database. The architecture is first I have Modules for top horizontal menus (Admin, Settings, Reports) then Sub Modules for left sidebar vertical menu headings (Users, Books) and the last one is Node which is expanded when clicking sub menu(User Management, Password Reset, Book Master, Book Lists).

```
        Admin    > Users > User Management
        Admin    > Books > Book Master
        Settings > Users > Password Reset
        Reports  > Books > Book Lists
```

Like this the node will come only once and modules and sub modules will be repeated.

There are five tables : menu_modules, menu_sub_modules, module_submodule_mapping, menu_nodes and submodule_node_mapping.

'menu_module fields' - menu_module_id, module_name, created_at, updated_at

'menu_sub_modules' fields - menu_sub_module_id, sub_module_name,created_at, updated_at

'module_submodule_mapping' fields - sub_module_mapping_id, menu_module_id, menu_sub_module_id,created_at, updated_at

'menu_nodes' fields - menu_node_id, node_name,created_at, updated_at

'submodule_node_mapping' - node_mapping_id, menu_sub_module_id, menu_node_id, created_at, updated_at

First I have to get results like this query using eloquent relationship in laravel 4:

```
SELECT A.module_name,B.sub_module_name FROM menu_module A,menu_sub_modules B,module_submodule_mapping C WHERE A.menu_module_id = C.menu_module_id AND B.menu_sub_module_id = C.menu_sub_module_id
```

Then the second result like this query:

```
SELECT A.node_name FROM menu_nodes A,submodule_node_mapping B WHERE A.menu_node_id = B.menu_node_id AND C.menu_sub_module_id = '1'
```

Can anyone explain the model structure and methods and also how to get the result in view. Please note that I am using my own id fields like menu_node_id and the project is in laravel 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe with what you are looking to do, you will have a less confusing time using the Query Builder as it has methods to perform joins on the tables.  This will require a little bit of a rebuilding of your table structures, but it should be easier to understand in the end.

menu_modules

1. id
2. name
3. created_at
4. updated_at

menu_sub_modules

1. id
2. name
3. menu_id (this is going to be a foreign key to menu_modules)
4. created_at
5. updated_at

menu_nodes

1. id
2. name
3. sub_id (this is going to be a foreign key to menu_sub_modules)
4. created_at
5. updated_at

Now with these foreign keys in place, we can use the query builder and not have to worry about the additional pivot tables.

```
DB::table('menu_modules')
->JOIN('menu_sub_modules', 'menu_sub_modules.menu_id', '=', 'menu_modules.id')
->JOIN('menu_nodes', 'menu_nodes.sub_id', '=', 'menu_sub_modules.id')
->get();
```